# Insert array of json data into json file using javascript & JSP

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, jsp

I have one function in my code which gives me x & y coordinates. I have formatted that data and saved that data into an array in JSON format. Now, want to save this variable data into a JSON file. Can anyone help me out from this? 
        The variable arrayData contains String of JSON data which I want to save to the new JSON file.
OR
Can I use JSP to save this data into JSON file? But the only problem here is, data is in JavaScript variable.

```
game.input.onDown.add(function() {
    x = Math.floor(game.input.activePointer.worldX / 15);
    y = Math.floor(game.input.activePointer.worldY / 15);
    arrayData.push("{'x':'" + x+"','Y':'"+y+"'}");
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = ' Data: {"x":' + x+',"Y":'+y+'}';
    console.log(" Data: " + arrayData);
});
```

Comment: You will need to use JSP to create the file. You pretty much just create a ajax request using javascript to hit your webservice in JSP which then creates the file with the posted input.

Comment: ok means you are saying on submit I will save this data into the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for replying to this question. The problem is solved. Actually, I send the javascript variable to JSP using Ajax post method. It was more than simple than I thought.`function check(){

```
 $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "CollectData.jsp",
      data: {xydata:arrayData},
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(resultData) {
          alert("here");
          console.log("New Data :"+resultData);
      //$("#list").html(resultData);
      }
});
```

}`

and finally, Saved into the JSON file

```
String data =request.getParameter("xydata"); 
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("arr", data);

try {
FileWriter file = new FileWriter("D:\\test\\testFile.json");
file.write(obj.toJSONString());
file.flush();
file.close();    
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to put your object between quotes: it will be a string. Change:

```
arrayData.push("{'x':'" + x+"','Y':'"+y+"'}");
```

To:

```
arrayData.push({'x': x,'Y': y});
```

---

Which is equivalent to:

```
var obj = {
    'x': Math.floor(game.input.activePointer.worldX / 15), 
    'y': Math.floor(game.input.activePointer.worldY / 15)
};
arrayData.push(obj);
```

Comment: Ohh, I did not think about that. Thank you !!  But can you suggest me about the question I have asked?